# Dealing with uninstantiated values in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Hello I'm very very very new to Prolog,
I have a predicate here that is taking uninstantiated values of Line and Column.

```
Call: (20) project: inside_square(position(_8924, _8926), shape(square, 2)) ? creep
```

I want Prolog to know and remember each values that are in the range of the Dimension of the square (backtracking) and use those values to solve a way bigger problem.
I'm using `member/2`, but the problem here is that it only takes the first value of the range, 1, and continue his backtracking (i noticed in `trace.`).

I don't know if I'm clear enough, it's hard to be when I can't give a full context but tell me if I'm not.

Can anyone explain to me with human words what is going on.

inside_square(position(Line,Column), shape(square,Dimension)) :-

```
 Dimension >= 0,
 findall(List, between(1,Dimension,List), Range),
 member(Column, Range),member(Line, Range),
 shape(square,Dimension).  %this line is not important here
```

**EDIT**
I Have tried something like this :

```
inside_square(position(Line,Column), shape(square,Dimension)) :-
     Dimension >= 0,
     between(1, Dimension, Line),between(1, Dimension, Column),
     shape(square,Dimension).
```

But i dont know if the backtracking will use all the positions values or not..

Comment: I think you want to look into [clpfd](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd) because it sounds like you're actually wanting to constrain the values of Line and Column without making a concrete decision about what they are, and that's exactly what CLPFD is for. Vanilla Prolog is probably not going to get there for you, at least, not without some pain.

Comment: I have to go through that pain because its an assignment T_T.

Comment: I have the Dimensions tho and since it's a square, Dimension x Dimension. :s, I just need to find a way or to understand why it only takes the first possibility in the list, and how I can make it take them all one by one..

Comment: Well, Prolog isn't logic, it has to start somewhere, and it's going to start at 1 because you specified that in your `between/3` call. As in your edit, if you want to materialize _all_ of the solutions at once, you will need to use a second-order predicate like `findall/3` or `setof/3` or `bagof/3`, each of which have interesting differences.

Comment: By the way, there really isn't a meaningful difference between `findall(Item, between(1,Dimension,Item), Range), member(Column, Range)` and `between(1, Dimension, Column).` In the former case you've materialized a list, but then you iterate it with `member/2`.

Comment: If you really want to just get all the possible positions, then you'd be just as well off with `findall(position(Line, Column), (between(1, Dimension, Line), between(1, Dimension, Column)), AllPositions)`.

Comment: show your sample call please and what is your specific question about it. "I have a predicate here that is taking uninstantiated values of Line and Column" no you do not. if I call `inside_square(position(1,2), shape(square,4))` then they do become instantiated at the instance the predicate is entered, because to call a predicate is to match the query and the predicate's *head* (where a predicate is defined as *head* `:-` *body*).

Comment: Call: (20) tp2: inside_square(position(_8924, _8926), shape(square, 2)) ? creep

Comment: is there an implementation of this predicate that can give me all the positions possible of X and Y? `inside_square(position(X,Y), shape(square,4))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my error.
I used a cut `!` in a higher predicate that was blocking the backtracking.